# Facing error TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable when sum total count

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a task to count symbols from multiple text files. I am near to finish but facing an issue. Below is my n I want to sum the `commaCount` value. I put command `total = sum(commacount)` but it shows error

```
total = sum(commaCount)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Here's my code:

```
import glob

def stats():

    commaCount = 0

    path = 'D:/Stiudies/Data/female/*.txt'
    inf = glob.glob(path)

    for name in inf:
        with open(name, 'r', encoding="utf8") as input_file:
            for line in input_file:
                for char in line:
                    if char == ',':
                        commaCount += 1

                        total = sum(commaCount)

            print(commaCount)

stats()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use count function like this:

```
a = "hi, hello, good by, , ,"

print(a.count(","))
```

it will show you:

5

but for your original code:

```
path = 'D:/Stiudies/Data/female/*.txt'
inf = glob.glob(path)

buffer_commas = 0

for name in inf:
    with open(name, 'r', encoding="utf8") as input_file:
        raw_data = input_file.read()
        buffer_commas = buffer_commas + raw.count(",")

print(buffer_commas)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help code is working fine. i want to count uppercase characters as well. Please help me with that. Thank you.

Comment: @MuhammadHafizTahir : use print(sum(1 for c in your_string if c.isupper()))

Answer (score 1):

The error comes form the fact that the built-in [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function expects to receive an argument that is something like a list of numbers (an 'iterable') that it will sum together. In your case, you are giving it `commaCount`, which is a single number (not an iterable).

However, by using:

`commaCount += 1`

you are already summing up all of the commas in all of the files, so there is no reason to do another `sum`. I think you can just remove that line.

Answer (score 1):

Following code helps to find number of ',' per file and total in list of files

```
import glob
path = 'D:\Stiudies\Data\female\*.txt'
inf = glob.glob(path)
commaCount = 0
for name in inf:
    with open(name, 'r') as input_file:
        count += input_file.read().count(',')
        print "Count:{}\t for file:{}:".format(count,name)
    commaCount +=count
print "Total count:", commaCount
```

Comment: Note that your current answer needs some adaptions for python 3. E.g. `print` vs `print()`.